# MYSQL query with two different join and count

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two different query that works good alone. The first gave me my useful result column `TOTALI` and the second query column `RIMBORSATI`. So I need to union the first query with the second and make that the HAVING clause of first query is an operation like HAVING `totali-rimborsati  < professionisti.limite`.

Thank u so much.

**First Query:**

```
SELECT professionisti.*,COUNT(contatti_acquistati_addebito.email) AS totali  
FROM professionisti
   LEFT JOIN contatti_acquistati_addebito ON
             professionisti.email = contatti_acquistati_addebito.email
           AND contatti_acquistati_addebito.DATA
               BETWEEN ('2014-05-01') AND  ('2014-05-31')
   WHERE professionisti.categoria LIKE '%0540%' AND 
         professionisti.province LIKE '%MI%'  
         AND   professionisti.addebito='1'
GROUP BY professionisti.email
HAVING totali  < professionisti.limite
ORDER BY totali ASC LIMIT 4
```

**Second Query:**

```
SELECT professionisti.*,COUNT(contatti_rimborsi.email) AS rimborsati  
FROM professionisti
LEFT JOIN contatti_rimborsi ON professionisti.email = contatti_rimborsi.email AND 
            contatti_rimborsi.DATA BETWEEN ('2014-05-01') AND  ('2014-05-31')
WHERE professionisti.categoria LIKE '%0540%'
      AND professionisti.province LIKE '%MI%'  
      AND professionisti.addebito='1'
GROUP BY professionisti.email
ORDER BY totali ASC LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SELECT p.*,m1.*,m2.*,IFNULL(m2.rimborsi, 0) as rimborsiok
  FROM professionisti p
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT ca.email, COUNT(*) AS totali
    FROM contatti_acquistati_addebito ca
                WHERE ca.data between ('2014-06-01') AND  ('2014-06-31')
    GROUP BY ca.email
  ) AS m1 ON p.email = m1.email
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT cr.email, COUNT(*) AS rimborsi
    FROM contatti_rimborsi cr
    WHERE cr.data between ('2014-06-01') AND  ('2014-06-31')
    GROUP BY cr.email
  ) AS m2 ON p.email = m2.email
WHERE p.categoria LIKE '%0540%' AND p.province LIKE '%MI%'  AND p.standby='0' AND p.addebito='1'
HAVING  m1.totali-rimborsiok<p.limite OR p.limite=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sq1.*,sq2.rimborsati  
from 
(SELECT professionisti.email as email, professionisti.categoria as categoria,professionisti.province as province,professionisti.addebito as addebito, COUNT(contatti_acquistati_addebito.email) AS totali  
FROM professionisti
   LEFT JOIN contatti_acquistati_addebito ON
             professionisti.email = contatti_acquistati_addebito.email
           AND contatti_acquistati_addebito.DATA
               BETWEEN ('2014-05-01') AND  ('2014-05-31')
   WHERE professionisti.categoria LIKE '%0540%' AND 
         professionisti.province LIKE '%MI%'  
         AND   professionisti.addebito='1'
GROUP BY professionisti.email
HAVING totali  < professionisti.limite
ORDER BY totali ASC LIMIT 4) sq1,

(SELECT professionisti.email as email, professionisti.categoria as categoria,professionisti.province as province,professionisti.addebito as addebito, COUNT(contatti_rimborsi.email) AS rimborsati  
FROM professionisti
LEFT JOIN contatti_rimborsi ON professionisti.email = contatti_rimborsi.email AND 
            contatti_rimborsi.DATA BETWEEN ('2014-05-01') AND  ('2014-05-31')
WHERE professionisti.categoria LIKE '%0540%'
      AND professionisti.province LIKE '%MI%'  
      AND professionisti.addebito='1'
GROUP BY professionisti.email
ORDER BY totali ASC LIMIT 4) sq2
where sq1.email=sq2.email and totali <rimborsati
```

Comment: :-( 
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS rimborsati
ORDER BY totali ASC LIMIT 4' at line 7


if i remove also HAVING clause query work but on column totali and rimborsi  have the same value and are wrong.

Comment: not work again :-(
remove having clause i'll restore by myself....anyway if i remove also HAVING clause query work but on column totali and rimborsi have the same value and are wrong.

Comment: for example if i run the first query alone totali is 10 and on second query rimborsati is 3 but with this i have 39 in both column :-(

Comment: Can try now and let me know what you get?

Comment: not work at all i also remove 
professionisti.column1 as column1....., etc....
give me
syntax to use near '(SELECT professionisti.email as email,COUNT(contatti_rimborsi.email) AS rimborsa' at line 16

Comment: yes :-(  i think that posble solution is nearby like this my last month question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914207/sql-join-two-simple-query-with-count-and-groupby/23914317#23914317

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.email,t1.limite,t1.totali,t2.rimborsati
from (
  SELECT professionisti.email,
    max(professionisti.limite) as limite,
    min(COUNT(contatti_acquistati_addebito.email) AS totali  
  FROM professionisti
     LEFT JOIN contatti_acquistati_addebito ON
             professionisti.email = contatti_acquistati_addebito.email
             AND contatti_acquistati_addebito.DATA
                 BETWEEN ('2014-05-01') AND  ('2014-05-31')
   WHERE professionisti.categoria LIKE '%0540%' AND 
             professionisti.province LIKE '%MI%'  
             AND professionisti.addebito='1'
   GROUP BY professionisti.email
   -- Here that professionisti.limite does make sense to me it should be an aggregate function!?
   -- (are you sure this query works?)
   -- using max(professionisti.limite) and using the aggregate count for email
   HAVING COUNT(contatti_acquistati_addebito.email)  < max(professionisti.limite)
   -- using aggregate more general sql (works better on other engines)
   -- removed see why below.
   -- ORDER BY COUNT(contatti_acquistati_addebito.email) ASC LIMIT 4
) t1
  left join (
    SELECT professionisti.email,COUNT(contatti_rimborsi.email) AS rimborsati  
    FROM professionisti
    LEFT JOIN contatti_rimborsi ON professionisti.email = contatti_rimborsi.email AND 
            contatti_rimborsi.DATA BETWEEN ('2014-05-01') AND  ('2014-05-31')
    WHERE professionisti.categoria LIKE '%0540%'
            AND professionisti.province LIKE '%MI%'  
            AND professionisti.addebito='1'
    GROUP BY professionisti.email
    -- Here you cannot order by totali you do not have it so I am removing both order by
    -- alternativly put the same left join with contatti_acquistati_addebito as above!
    -- ORDER BY totali ASC LIMIT 4
) t2 on t1.email=t2.email
where ,t1.totali-t2.rimborsati  < t1.limite
```